# @> Operator not working on int2[] type

Tags: postgresql

I have a column with a type of int2[] array. And I want to make IN query on this column.

I search it on google and found the @> operator to search in array columns but it seems not working on int2 type array columns. But it works on int[]

Has anybody know why it doesn't work on int2[]?

```
ecabuk=# CREATE TABLE "Test"("Column1" int2[]);
CREATE TABLE

ecabuk=# INSERT INTO "Test" VALUES ('{10, 15, 20}');
INSERT 0 1

ecabuk=# INSERT INTO "Test" VALUES ('{10, 20, 30}');
INSERT 0 1

ecabuk=# EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * FROM "Test" WHERE "Column1" @> ARRAY[20];
ERROR:  operator does not exist: smallint[] @> integer[]
LINE 1: ...LAIN ANALYZE SELECT * FROM "Test" WHERE "Column1" @> ARRAY[2...
                                                             ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.

ecabuk=# ALTER TABLE "Test" ALTER COLUMN "Column1" type int[];
ALTER TABLE

ecabuk=# EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * FROM "Test" WHERE "Column1" @> ARRAY[20];
                                            QUERY PLAN                                            
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Seq Scan on "Test"  (cost=0.00..26.38 rows=7 width=32) (actual time=0.200..0.204 rows=2 loops=1)
   Filter: ("Column1" @> '{20}'::integer[])
 Total runtime: 0.256 ms
(3 rows)

ecabuk=#
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you specify ARRAY[20] it is treating that as an int[] rather than an int2[].  Suitable casts will make it behave.

```
test=# EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * FROM "Test" WHERE "Column1" @> ARRAY[2];
ERROR:  operator does not exist: smallint[] @> integer[]
LINE 1: ...LAIN ANALYZE SELECT * FROM "Test" WHERE "Column1" @> ARRAY[2...
                                                             ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
test=# EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * FROM "Test" WHERE "Column1" @> ARRAY[20::int2];
                                            QUERY PLAN

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Seq Scan on "Test"  (cost=0.00..26.38 rows=7 width=32) (actual time=0.060..0.064 rows=2 loops=1)
   Filter: ("Column1" @> '{20}'::smallint[])
 Total runtime: 0.116 ms
(3 rows)


test=# EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * FROM "Test" WHERE "Column1" @> ARRAY[20]::int2[];
                                            QUERY PLAN

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Seq Scan on "Test"  (cost=0.00..26.38 rows=7 width=32) (actual time=0.028..0.032 rows=2 loops=1)
   Filter: ("Column1" @> '{20}'::smallint[])
 Total runtime: 0.080 ms
(3 rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

Works here. You'll need to provide an example of it failing I'm afraid:

```
=> SELECT ARRAY[1,2,3]::int2[] @> ARRAY[1,2]::int2[];
 ?column? 
----------
   t
  (1 row)

=> SELECT ARRAY[1,2,3]::int2[] @> ARRAY[3,4]::int2[];
 ?column? 
----------
  f
 (1 row)
```

It would be odd if it didn't work because it's defined over anyarray:

```
=> \do '@>'
                               List of operators

   Schema   | Name | Left arg type | Right arg type | Result type | Description 
------------+------+---------------+----------------+-------------+-------------
 pg_catalog | @>   | aclitem[]     | aclitem        | boolean     | contains
 pg_catalog | @>   | anyarray      | anyarray       | boolean     | contains
 ...
```

Tested in 9.1 and 9.2